# Question about a paper by Franca and LeClair in analytic number theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, l-functions

I am reading an article *"Transcendental equations satisfied by the individual
zeros of Riemann $\zeta$, Dirichlet and modular
L-functions"* by G. Franca and A. LeClair (2015) [see here](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cntp/2015/0009/0001/CNTP-2015-0009-0001-a001.pdf). The authors start with the completed Riemann zeta function $\chi(s):=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$ where $s=\sigma+it$. Now we have the Stirling's approximation $\Gamma(s)\simeq \sqrt{2\pi}s^{s-1/2}e^{-s}$, valid for large $t$. So we have under these conditions $$s^s=\exp\{i\left(t\log t+\frac{\pi\sigma}{2}\right)+\sigma\log t-\frac{\pi t}{2}+\sigma+O(t^{-1})\}$$
Now using the polar representation $\zeta=|\zeta|e^{i\arg \zeta}$ and the above expansions, we can write $\chi(s)=Ae^{i\theta}$ where $$A(\sigma,t)=\sqrt{2\pi}\pi^{-\sigma/2}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^{(\sigma-1)/2}e^{-\pi t/4} |\zeta(\sigma+it)|(1+O(s^{-1})),$$ $$\theta(\sigma,t)=\frac{t}{2}\log\left(\frac{t}{2\pi e}\right)+\frac{\pi}{4}(\sigma-1)+\arg\zeta(\sigma+it)+O(t^{-1}) .$$
Now let $\rho=\sigma+it$ be a Riemann zero then the authors define $\arg\zeta(\rho)$ as $$\arg\zeta(\rho):=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\arg\zeta(\sigma+\delta+it) $$
Now $\overline{\chi(s)}=\chi(\bar{s})$ implies that $A(\sigma,-t)=A(\sigma,t)$ and $\theta(\sigma,-t)=-\theta(\sigma,t)$, Denoting $\chi(1-s)=A'e^{-i\theta'}$ we have $$A'(\sigma,t)=A(1-\sigma,t),\ \ \theta'(\sigma,t)=\theta(1-\sigma,t) $$
Also we have from the functional equation $\chi(s)=\chi(1-s)$, $A(\sigma,t)=A'(\sigma,t)$ for any $s$ on the critical strip.

Then the authors approach a zero $\rho=\sigma+it$ through the $\delta\to 0^+$ limit. So we have$$\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}[\chi(\rho+\delta)+\chi(1-\rho-\delta)]=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+} A(\sigma+\delta,t) B(\sigma+\delta,t)$$ where they define $$B(\sigma,t):=e^{i\theta(\sigma,t)}+e^{-i\theta'(\sigma,t)} $$ Then they consider $B=0$ first whose general solution is $$\theta+\theta'=(2n+1)\pi $$
and the particular solution of $B=0$ is $$\theta=\theta',\ \lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\cos \theta=0 $$
On the critical line $\sigma=\frac{1}{2}$, we get $\lim_{\delta\to 0^+} \theta\left(\frac{1}{2}+\delta,t\right)=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$ for $n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,...,$ hence labelling the zeros by $\rho_n=\frac{1}{2}+it_n$ $$\frac{t_n}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{t_n}{2\pi e}\right)+\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\pi}\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+\delta+it_n\right) =n-\frac{11}{8} $$

**Question:** The author requires in the last equation that the LHS should be monotonically increasing function of $t$. How in the LHS of the last equation we don't have $O(t^{-1})$ term (which should be there due to the first equation)? Under what conditions can we replace $n$ by $N_0(T)+C$ where $N_0(T)$ is the number of zeros of Riemann zeta function on the critical line upto height $T$ and $C$ is a constant?

I would really appreciate for some help. Is the article not suitable for math purposes as noted by @Conrad?

**edit** So according to the comments and its 4 upvotes, is the above paper mathematically incorrect?

Comment: this is written by physicists so it's lots of handwaving and would ignore it for math purposes

Comment: @Conrad Thank you. Does the author requires the LHS of last equation including $O(t^{-1})$ term to be increasing or just the terms as written in last equation?

Comment: @Conrad Please clarify your comment. I am unable to understand it.

Comment: My comment says that the paper lacks math rigor so I would treat any claim in it warily and as unproven

Comment: @Conrad But then the paper is published in a reputed journal? It says that if LHS of equation (13) is well defined for any $t$ and monotonically increasing then almost all the zeros of the Riemann zeta function are on the critical line.

Comment: It's a physics journal so different rigor standards than math; as noted feel free to make sense of it but personally I am not going to waste time on it as it's handwaving - maybe look up gram points in Edwards book on RZ for a rigurous treatment of this stuff

Comment: Please stop pestering user Conrad (and please don't start pestering me).